# $connection->next_result() analog for SafeMySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When MySQL stored procedure returns an result set, you can get error "Commands out of sync".
When connecting to DB with mysqli this error can be fixed with this code:

```
<?php
  // Assuming $connection is your MySQLI object
  while($connection->next_result()) $connection->store_result();
?>
```

How to fix this error when connecting to DB with SafeMySQL class?

Answer (score 0):

remember to close your result set

```
$result->close();
 $connection->next_result();
```